# HTML/CSS colors. Where I can find it?

Tags: css, html

Can you look at this site http://176.112.192.242:3174  and tell me where is rose color in right top corner come from??? I use Firefox inspector, but i can't identify css or html file, where i can change this color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the background color on the form element. This is the corresponding CSS:

```
background-color: #fe988a;

.ct-navbarSelect::before, 
.ct-navbarSelect::after
```

in style.css line 3956

Answer (score 1):

It,is there in the background color on the form. This is coming from the class from stylesheet and property:

background-color: #fe988a;

.ct-navbarSelect::before, 
.ct-navbarSelect::after

Answer (score -1):

The color is `rgb(162, 43, 123)` or `#A22B7B` if you prefer to use HEX